# Figure appears in the middle of my longtable

Tags: longtable

I have a latex file with a 'longtable' in it, which spans a couple of pages. I added a new figure earlier in the document, and now, the figure appears in the middle of my longtable - i.e. it splits it in two. Obviously I don't want this to happen.

I am having difficulty supplying a MWE, because the text and figures are part of an academic document which I cannot share, but when I remove parts of the text, everything gets shuffled around and the problem goes away.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Figures you can replace with `example-image` provided by package `graphics, instead real text you can use `\lipsum` from package `lipsum`. Without seeing the MWE, which show your problem is difficult to help you. Wild guess: see if figure option `[!ht] can help, or option `[H]`

Comment: \clearpage will force the figure to print immediately (and start a new page).  You can turn off top floats temporarily using \def\topfraction{0} inside a group.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions of Zarko and  John Kormylo? Can you give some feedback? If you need more fine control over the text length then `\lipsum`, try either different paragraphs if lipsum `\lipsum[2]` or just copy and paste `text` as often as needed - but without seeing some code that produces the problem, its really hard to try to help you.

Comment: I would also suggest trying to supply an MWE with dummy text, dummy figures and dummy data in the table, otherwise recreating the problem in this instance is close to impossible.

For dummy table data, you could use a free only service like [mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/), which is able to generate realistic data that can easily be exported. From a CSV export to a LaTeX table is as easy as automatically replacing "," with " & " and "\n" with "\\\n". How text and figures can be replaced was already covered in the previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the package `float` and use the `H` option.

```
\usepackage{float}
...
\begin{documment}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        your figure
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

this option makes the figure to not float, but stay where it was in your code

Comment: Hmm, when I did that, the figure just didn't appear at all. Is it possible that it's overlapped by the table?

Comment: Oh yeah I had {figure*} - when I removed the asterisk, the figure appeared, but it was only partially only the page and it was overlaid by the main text of the document.

Comment: is the figure big? is there anything between the figure and the table?

Comment: Yeah, the figure is about 2/3 the height of the page. There is the figure, then a bunch of text (in the tex document) and then the table.

Comment: try to add an example using the lipsum package, which produces a long dummy text, an image big like yours and a table long like yours. I think this is a problem with the alignment os the text. is it inside a multicols, minipage, parbox, or something else? are you using the wrapfig environment?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is before the table, a call to \clearpage will force all images that come before the call to print ensuring that any previous images won't interfere with your table.